# Accessing the image that's clicked in a link with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have a link that I'd like to manipulate with jQuery:

```
<a href="http://example.com/images/big_dog.jpg" >
    <img src= "http://example.com/images/small_dog.jpg" style="position:absolute; left:198; top:67; width:170">
</a>
```

When the small dog is clicked the big dog appears.

The `href` attribute, the big dog, is easy. I can just do `.attr('href')`. But how do I access the `<img>` part of the link, i.e., the small dog that gets clicked?

A `find()` from the `<a>` doesn't seem right since the `img` is actually part of the `<a>` element.

Comment: .find() should work just fine, show your failing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `img` tag in the example is a child of the `a` tag. So to get the value of the src attribute:

```
$(this).children("img").attr("src");
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YvPjK/)

Answer (score 1):

@imbondbaby is right with the children part. If you want to use find and you were not able to do so here is an example how to use that:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','http://portablegamingregion.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Apple-and-Google-logo-Thumbnail1.png');
});
```

Example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8LtP/)

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I was thinking there was more to it, that <img> was some kind of a attribute of <a>, like href.

Comment: @Steve you can have the click event straight away on the img tag instead of wrapping it up in an anchor tag if you like. You will avoid the find and children method in that case Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/C8LtP/1/ (if anchor tag is not required and does not have multiple children)

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually building up links to feed to Fancybox, though, and it expects an `<a>` with an <img> inside.